# Error Handling for Computed Column Primary Key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on an ASP.NET Web API application where I have a controller method responsible for accepting JSON data and invoking a repository method to create a new customer entity. The customer entity has a computed column primary key named "UserID" that should follow a specific format, such as "USER001".

**Controller Method:** My controller method responsible for creating a new customer entity looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesDefaultResponseType]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] CustomerDTO value)
{
    // I use Riok Mapperly to map CustomerDTO to Customer entity

    int result = _customerRepository.CreateCustomer(customer);
    if (result is not 0)
    {
        return Ok(value);
    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("Wrong Input");
    }
}
```

**Entity Configuration:** I have configured the Customer entity in my application using Entity Framework Core as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>(entity =>
{ 
    entity.Property(e => e.UserId)
        .HasMaxLength(7)
        .IsUnicode(false)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("('USER'+right('000'+CONVERT( ,[ID]),(3)))")
        .HasColumnName("UserID");
});
```

**SQL Server Table Schema:** Here's the table schema from SQL Server that I've scaffolded:

```
CREATE TABLE [Customers] (
    [UserID]     AS             ('USER'+right('000'+CONVERT([varchar](3),[ID]),(3))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    [ID]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]  NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [LastName]   NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [MiddleName] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Company]    NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Street1]    NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [City]       NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [State]      NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Zip]        NVARCHAR (20)  NOT NULL,
    [Country]    NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [Email]      NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserID] ASC)
);
```

Here's a snippet of the JSON data I'm trying to send to the API:

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "middleName": "Chris",
  "company": "ABC Company",
  "street1": "123 Main St",
  "city": "New York",
  "state": "NY",
  "zip": "10001",
  "country": "USA",
  "email": "john.doe@example.com"
}
```

**Problem Encountered:**

- If I don't append **`.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`** to the configuration of **`User_ID`**, I encounter the following error:

  System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'UserId' cannot be configured as 'ValueGeneratedOnUpdate' or 'ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate' because it's part of a key and its value cannot be changed after the entity has been added to the store.
- If I do append **`.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()`**, I see the following error:

  SqlException: The column "UserID" cannot be modified because it is either a computed column or is the result of a UNION operator.

I'm seeking guidance on how to properly configure the computed column primary key (UserID) in Entity Framework Core to avoid the aforementioned errors. I want the UserID column to be automatically generated based on the format specified in the HasComputedColumnSql method, while ensuring that it behaves correctly within the context of my ASP.NET Web API application.

Any help or insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why is `UserID` the primary key and not `ID`?

Comment: It's "derived" data. You might just as well add it as a function to the entity (Class). You will generally have to give the user the ability to search by "Name", etc. I doubt that "USERXXX" type queries will play much of a part.

Comment: Because I require the UserID as the global identifier for the Customer attribute. I am a novice developer endeavoring to comprehend EF Core and SQL Server.